# Application Hangs while extracting data

Tags: php, mysql

I have noticed several times. we have a front end application created in php. it can extract data from MySQL database into excel file. when I extract data if data is less (about 1000 rows) it creates an  excel file normally size of 1-2 MB. but application hangs or gives connection time out whenever I extract more data (about 100000 rows). do I have to change some parameters in php.ini file? I think this might be an error of memory allocation. but not sure which parameter to change.

Comment: The connection time-out mainly means that your script went time-out because it took to long to execute..

Comment: I know but this is just one of the error I get... most of the times application work perfectly. but I can't extract more data. application just does not respond..

Comment: This sounds like it needs to be done [from command line](http://www.php-cli.com/) rather than from a server. (when you run a PHP script from command line by default there is no timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into PHP's output buffer. You can send data as it becomes available.

Look at this for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php and this as an example http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2013/08/output-csv-straight-to-browser-using-php/

Edit: Just a thought, you can monitor the status of your database (in case it's the issue here). In your MySQL client you can execute this command `show processlist;` repeatedly to see what state the DB is in. If your script times out after the query has successfully completed, you can rule out a long running query.

Also if you're concerned about memory, you shouldn't put all your data in one variable. Really what you should be doing is writing out as you get information in.  Seeing your code would help, but basically something along the lines of:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<td>{$result['firstname']}</td>";
}
```

is much better than:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: thanks ajacian81 really helped..will look at the front end code now

Comment: one more thing I have noticed is that this error just occurs when I extract in excel 2007 (.xlsx) format. I changed it to extract in (.csv) format .. and it works..